# Too many connection.release

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I'm using `node-mysql` with pool connection to handle database stuff. Everything is great, but the way connection is released. It seems that `connection.release()` need calling at anytime an event is going to be ended. This is very inconvenient and also make my code a lot more uglier.

```
db.getConnection(function(error,conn){
    if(error){
         conn.release();
         throw error;
    }
    conn.query(query1,value1,function(err,result){
         if(err){
              conn.release();
              throw err;
         }
         if(!value1){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         if(!value2){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         ...
         ...
         ...
         if(!valueN){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         conn.release();
    });
    conn.query(query2,value2,function(err,result){
         if(err){
              conn.release();
              throw err;
         }
         if(!value1){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         if(!value2){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         ...
         ...
         ...
         if(!valueN){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         conn.release();
    });
    ...
    ...
    ...
    conn.query(queryN,valueN,function(err,result){
         if(err){
              conn.release();
              throw err;
         }
         if(!value1){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         if(!value2){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         ...
         ...
         ...
         if(!valueN){
             return conn.release();
         }
         // do something here
         conn.release();
    });
});
```

I feel that this problem is so real. How can I avoid it?

Comment: This will need Refactoring your code. Refactor your code so as to minimize number of returns from each of the function. That will reduce your conn.release() call as well.

Comment: What happens if each of my `if(!value)` statement is an async function. And each its callback contains an `error` argument. How can refactoring be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

just enclose your code in a try statement and then put a finally block with conn.release:

```
conn.query(query1,value1,function(err,result){

    try {
     if(err){
          throw err;
     }
     if(!value1){
         return;
     }
     // do something here
     if(!value2){
         return;
     }
     // do something here
     ...
     ...
     ...
     if(!valueN){
         return;
     }
   }
   finally { conn.release(); }
});
```

finally block is going to be executed whatever happen (with exception of System.Exit)